# What is a normalized range of values?

Tags: python, anonymity

I'm studying k-anonymization and the mondrian algorithm proposed by LeFevre. In it, LeFevre says that at one point in his algorithm, we have to choose a feature in the Dataframe depending on which feature has the largest range of normalized values.

For example, if I have the feature `Age` in my dataset with the values:
`[13, 15, 24, 30]`, I understand that the range is `13-30`, but as soon as you make it normalized wouldn't it always be `[0-1]`?

I know that the question seems strange, but I couldn't find anything on the internet nor on the paper itself that documented more what he meant.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchNMF.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a normalization technique but yes. If we use min max it will always be between `[0,1]`. What you can do is split that variable into segments and the normalized your data. However you use minx-max normalization, the minimum value of that feature gets transformed into a `0`, and the maximum value gets a `1`. Maybe a
mean normalization could give you a different result in that case.